# How setup VSCode + Chrome Debugger + Docker in MacOS (Docker for Mac)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Docker for Mac (Version 18.06.1-ce-mac74 (26766)) and I needed to configure the Google Chrome Debugger in VSCode. The configurations found on the internet did (How https://medium.com/@drcallaway/debugging-es6-in-visual-studio-code-4444db797954) not work for me. I share how I configured everything to work:

Answer (score 18):

#### Structure Project

```
/.vscode
  /launch.json
/admin
  /node_modules
  /public
  /src
  /package.json
/docker-compose.yaml
```

#### /.vscode/launch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations":{
    "name": "Chrome",
    "type": "chrome",
    "request": "launch",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/admin/src",
    "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
      "/srv/my-admin/src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
    },
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
    ]
  }
}
```

#### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  node:
    image: node:8.11.4-alpine
    working_dir: /srv
    volumes:
      - $PWD/admin:/srv/my-admin
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 9222:9222
    command: yarn --cwd my-admin start
```

Try and fun!!!

Comment: Nothing close to this available anywhere. Thanks for the clarity on all the important parts of the config.

Comment: kudos for documenting this as part of your question from github

Comment: Thanks, I needed the `sourceMapPathOverrides` to map the path in the container to the actual path on the host (for debugging). That solved it.

Comment: This works like a charm! however, you might want to edit your answer and remove the port 9222 from the docker compose file, as the browser is running in your host it isn't really needed to map that port into the container.